How to debug database triggers in Azure Cosmos db?
I have a database trigger in my cosmos db which is supposed to be executed on delete operation on my collection.
string triggerid = "trg-UpdateUserAssignedLocations-onDelete-Location";
string idtodelete = "9ff71836-bc95-489e-8cf0-110f4f01e50c";
var partitionKey = new PartitionKey("Location1);

await this.container.DeleteItemAsync<Location>(
    idtodelete, 
    partitionKey, 
    new ItemRequestOptions() { 
        PostTriggers=new List<string>() { triggerid },   
    }
);

Due to some reason the trigger is not getting executed or its getting errored out. How can I troubleshoot this? Is there any way we can provide console.log() inside triggers?
Here is how I created my trigger.

function updateUserAssignedLocationsOnFacilityDeletion(){
   var context = getContext();
    var request = context.getRequest();
    var collection = context.getCollection();

    var itemToDelete = request.getBody();
    if(itemToDelete.Type=='UserLocation' && itemToDelete.SystemName=='Facility'){
        id = itemToDelete.id;
        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(),
            'SELECT VALUE c FROM c JOIN a IN c.AllowedLocations WHERE a.Id = \''+id+'\' AND c.Type=\'User\'',
            function (err, feed, options) {
                if (err) throw err;

                if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                    var response = getContext().getResponse();
                    //response.setBody('no docs found');
                }
                else {
                    if(feed!=null){
                        feed.forEach((currentValue, index, arr)=>{
                            var arr = currentValue.AllowedLocations.filter(item => item.Id !== id)
                            currentValue.AllowedLocations = arr;

                            var accept = collection.replaceDocument(currentValue._self,
                                currentValue, function(err, itemReplaced) {
                                        if(err) throw "Unable to update user, abort";
                                });
                    
                            if(!accept) throw "Unable to update user, abort";
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}


var partitionKey = new PartitionKey("UserLocation"); - is "UserLocation" the property name, or the actual value? It needs to be the actual value.

its the actual value.@DavidMakogon
